# how to download database from united nations website

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, database

i need to get database for translation system and the UN databases provide what i need in the web page but i don't know how to download it?

how can i download database from united nations databases that contain translated words from English to Arabic?

thanx

Comment: what is the db url? i'm assuming you're going to have to scrape it, but no clue without looking at it....

Comment: @albert this is the link http://unterm.un.org/UNTERM/search?urlQuery=school                                                                                                        so, how can i download it to get all words and its translation as database

Comment: ok....still confused, sorry. where is the translation system/un database located in that document? or is it the whole document?